# Getting user's locale in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

I am working on an AIR desktop application, and am trying to get the user's locale string. I basically need to know whether the user's locale is English or French. `Capabilities.language` doesn't seem to work for me, as it only displays the OS's UI language.

How can I get the user's current locale?

Once determined, I intend to set it to `resourceManager.localeChain`, so that the appropriate 'properties' files are used to display my UI literals.

Thanks in advance!

Pritin

Comment: What is the difference between a user's locale and their OS's UI Language?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, If you see the documentation for `Capabilities.language`, it says it returns the UI language. Even if you change your system's locale ([link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows7/Change-the-system-locale)) to "French", the UI language is still English, and `Capabilities.language` still returns "en". I am looking for a way to determine the locale (fr_FR), instead of the UI language (which may be English). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Getting the users locality is nothing trivial.  All websites has had this problem, which is why they always ask you where you're from and which language do you want it to be.  This is no different in Flex.

Even with a way to detect the locale I would keep some sort of 'language bar' somewhere for the user to easily change his/her settings.

Comment: I'm building a desktop application, not a website. I guess your tutorial is specific to websites!

Comment: Then try to do `LocaleID.DEFAULT` which should return the system's locale.  I'm not sure if it's properly formatted though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using **Capabilities** Property **language** use [languages](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#languages) which returns an array Also see [Localizing AIR applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSB2927578-20D8-4065-99F3-00ACE6511EEE.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: this too returns only the OS's UI display languages!